# Angular directive with ng-attr bound to model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**[All code and preview in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjmfV1?p=preview)**

I want to double-bind an attribute to directive scope and changing that attribute from outside
it changes something inside the directive.

```
<body ng-app="paneApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="pane.a" btn-checkbox>A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="pane.b" btn-checkbox>B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="pane.c" btn-checkbox>C</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="pane.d" btn-checkbox>D</button>
  </div> 

  Visible: {{pane.a}} {{pane.b}} {{pane.c}} {{pane.d}}

  <pane-container>
    <pane ng-attr-hidden="{{pane.a}}">A</pane>
    <pane>B</pane> 
    <pane>C</pane>
    <pane>D</pane>
  </pane-container>
</body>
```

The error here is:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'pane.a' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{pane.a}}] starting at [pane.a}}].
```

If not using an expression inside the attirbute, all works as expected:

```
        <pane ng-attr-hidden="{{pane.a}}">A</pane>
```

### Edit:

This example is working as expected: [preview in plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/DpANjf/preview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming `ng-attr-hidden` expects an angular expression, but you're giving it an object definition.
Try removing the `{{}}`

```
<pane ng-attr-hidden="pane.a">A</pane>
```

Comment: This partially works, at least it doesn't throw an error. Why [in documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_-attribute-bindings) the example is `<circle ng-attr-cx="{{cx}}"></circle>`?

Comment: Ok, this works. So is the documentation wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: The documentation is not wrong, it's just really confusing (welcome to Angularjs).  In your directive, you are binding to your scope rather than having the template processed by the [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) service. So basically you are binding your directive's `$scope.hidden` to the outer `$scope.xxxx` where xxxx is whatever you put in the attribute.