# Angular SVG Directive Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I'm creating an Angular directive which wraps around the SVG line element as part of a larger component.

I started splitting up the constituent parts of the full SVG into smaller sections and the line directive is throwing syntax errors.

```
/**                                                                                                                                                
 * @name triadLine                                                                                                                                 
 * @type directive                                                                                                                                 
 * @overview                                                                                                                                       
 */                                                                                                                                                
.directive('triadLine', function(TriadConfig) {                                                                                                    
  return {                                                                                                                                         
    restrict: 'E',                                                                                                                                 
    replace: true,                                                                                                                                 
    scope: {                                                                                                                                       
      x1: '=',                                                                                                                                     
      y1: '=',                                                                                                                                     
      x2: '=',                                                                                                                                     
      y2: '='                                                                                                                                      
    },                                                                                                                                             
    link: function(scope) {                                                                                                                        
      scope.config = TriadConfig;                                                                                                                  
    },                                                                                                                                             
    template:                                                                                                                                      
    "<line " +                                                                                                                                     
        "ng-attr-x1='{{x1}}'" +                                                                                                                    
        "ng-attr-y1='{{y1}}'" +                                                                                                                    
        "ng-attr-x2='{{x2}}'" +                                                                                                                    
        "ng-attr-y2='{{y2}}'" +                                                                                                                    
        "style='stroke:{{config.line.stroke}}'>" +                                                                                                 
    "</line>"                                                                                                                                      
};
```

When the directive is compiled, Angular throws the following error:

> `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 3 of the expression [0 {{x1}}] starting at [{{x1}}].`

The problem isn't unique to the first binding either. If I remove that first line, the same problem is thrown for `y1`.

If I remove the `ng-attr-` lines, then I can see that the values are passed down correctly.

```
{
  ...
  config: Object
  x1: 300
  x2: 300
  y1: 80.3847577293368
  y2: 340.1923788646684
  ...
}
```

Have I missed some edge case about how Angular attribute directives work with SVGs?

Answer (score 0):

x1 is two-way binding variable. Can you please check where the triad-line directive is used the attribute x1 does not contain {{}}.

```
<triad-line x1="{{someScopeVariable}}">
```

Should be

```
<triad-line x1="someScopeVariable">
```

Comment: Yeah, it is. If it wasn't the variables would never have shown up in the child  scope, due to a compile error.

Comment: Is line a directive (with 2 way binding attributes)? Have typically come across this error when attribute parsing expects objects but instead expression is passed. A related one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171502/angular-directive-with-ng-attr-bound-to-model

Comment: `<line>` is an SVG element, `<triad-line>` is a directive with 2-way binding attributes, as defined above. The instances of `<triad-line>` are called with the variables bound rather than templated.